# Windows IP Configuration = How to specify Pointopoint

Tags: windows, networking, ip

where is the equivalent to the linux pointopoint command in Windows?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static                                 
 address <guest ip>                                        
 gateway <host external ip>
 netmask 255.255.255.255                                        
 pointopoint <host external ip>
```

I have looked in Windows Vista and there is nothing. they only offer IP, Subnet and Standardgatway.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: There's no direct equivalent in Vista; what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Chris very much. I need to run Vista in a Virtual Machine (KVM Environment) and my gateway (of the host) is in a completely different subnet then the IPs of my Guest. In linux everything is working fine with the settings above with the "pointopoint" and I was looking for an aquivalent statement in windows...

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure the networking to use a /30 network. Use the first host address for Linux and the second host address for the guest.